# How to kill a transient buffer?

Tags: kill-buffer, transients

I'm a emacs 28.0.50 user (compiled by my own) and my config is based on spacemacs v0.200.8

I've noticed that, when I'm on a transient buffer and type 'q', the buffer goes away but still in my buffers list.

How can I set some key to actually kill a transient buffer?

Thanks for your attention

Comment: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/0333173f184cab8dffa155edf81ff94185c8a3b4/layers/%2Bspacemacs/spacemacs-navigation/packages.el#L428 is something defined something like that in your definition ?

Comment: I probably should have mentioned it in my question, but I'm actually using spacemacs! So yes, there is something like that in my config.

Comment: It can be really nice if you can give more info. Like I tried this transient state in spacemacs and result is like that. + I am using this version of emacs this version of spacemacs etc etc. Currently nobody can reproduce your error. This makes it hard to solve.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @itirazimvar. I edited my question adding my version info. Also, by taking a closer look at the link you sent, it seems that the key 'q' is configured to exit transient state. However, I wanted it to exit transient state AND kill the corresponding buffer.